# Why the "define" options not work in vite2 when i package project?

Tags: vue.js, vite

i define the process.config in vite.config.js such as this

```
  define: {
    'process.env': {
      publishDate: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      version: pkg.version,
      title: pkg.title
    }
  },
```

in dev mode ,it works,
but in prod mode, the process.config is unfound.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not doing things as [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/#define) suggests:

> Type: `Record<string, string>`
>
> For example, `process.env.FOO` and `__APP_VERSION__` are good fits. But `process` or `global` should not be put into this option.
>
> it's implemented as straightforward text replacements without any syntax analysis

The map should be a string to string, not string to object. So you can write:

```js
define: {
    'process.env.publishDate': JSON.stringify(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
  },
```